# Finding Caller of ContentResolver.notifyChange

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, contentobserver

I have an activity for updating a table which holds configuration data for a service.  I am using a SimpleCursorLoader and the SupportLoaderManager to update the listview in that Activity.  I destroy the loader in In the activity's onDestroy.  This may not be relevant, since the issue I'm seeing happens even without visiting this Activity.

I have a service as well, that registers a ContentObserver on the URI to the table that is modified in the Activity above.  It reads its configuration, sets itself up and registers a ContentObserver on that table in the Service's onCreate.  In the Service's onDestroy, that listener is unregistered.

This is only 1 of a few databases/tables that I have in my system.  What I'm seeing is that when I make an update to a completely different table, the ContentObserver on this configuration URI is being triggered.  The Authorities are completely different, they interact with different SqlLite databases, they're even running in different processes within the application.  I removed all "notifyChange" calls that I could find which would trigger the ContentObservers, yet they still are firing.

My question is, is there any way to find out who is calling the notifyChange that is causing the ContentObserver to fire?  Does the system outside of my application have any reason to notify observers of a URI?  I'm trying to track it down, but without having any clue where the notify is coming from, I'm running into a wall.

Answer (score 0):

Again, only a few hours away from the answer.  I apparently didn't find all of the notifyChange calls in my code.  The offender was:

```
getContentResolver.notifyChange(new Uri.Builder().build(), null);
```

which was calling notify on a blank Uri.  It doesn't appear to be noted in the documentation, but the behavior I saw was that this triggered all of the registered ContentObservers to be fired in my application.  I got that line out of there, and now everything is notifying as it should.

The answer to my original question, "Is there a way to find out who called notifyChange on a Uri?," I think the answer is "Look harder for calls to notifyChange in your code.  Other than that, you're on your own."